# How PPPoE uses addressing to know destination Mac address?

Tags: router, mac-address, layer2, pppoe, ppp

**Case.1** We know that when router connected via point to point(PPP) protocol then ARP isn't used to know the destination Mac address.

**Case.2** When two router connected via PPP as well as Ethernet which is PPPoE, then also ARP isn't used to know destination Mac address.

My question is for **case2** PPPoE **request** frame is used to know the destination Mac address?

And in PPPoE **request** frame PPP is also used as well as in Ethernet frame PPPoE frame(which contained PPP frame) also used to know the destination Mac address?

And in Ethernet frame destination address should be ff:ff:ff:ff?

Like the below image:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're getting too hung up on the ethernet side of the equation. Yes, ethernet is a multi-point medium. PPPoE *does not* use it that way. The PPPoE discovery/setup process creates a single, one-to-one path across the multi-point ethernet medium. Typically, there's only one server, so all clients learn the MAC from it's broadcasts; the server then learns the various individual clients when they transmit. If there are multiple servers, a client can associate with any of them, including all of them. (if there are multiple ISPs on a shared link, you'll only be associating with *your* ISP(s))

Keep in mind, PPPoE may only be ethernet for a few feet -- between the customer's router and ISP's modem. I've seen it terminate on the DSLAM, as well as transported across the country (USA) via tunnels to a single, central server. (i.e. wholesale DSL)

Comment: Pppoe with Ehthnet you said multiple devices are possible through switch. But only PPP more than one relationships are possible? Or with PPP only two devices connection are possible by one link?

Comment: A PPPoE session is a single, one-to-one connection. There can be more than one session on a link -- that's why the protocol has a session id. Just like TCP is a single, one-to-one connection, where there are more one connection per link.

Comment: That's understand. But I am asking without using Pppoe, if I using only PPP then more than one session on a link is possible?

Comment: You can't use PPP over Ethernet without the addition of the PPPoE protocol bits ("PPPoE packet encapsulation format") because ethernet is not a point-to-point medium - there aren't just two nodes on an ethernet network. (even when their might physically only be two, the medium is designed for more. MACs **must** be used to identify nodes.)

Comment: Ethernet is not a point-to-point but a multipoint technology (even when two devices are connected back to back). Ethernet is designed to allow multiple devices to share a common medium, called a “broadcast domain”.

Answer (score 2):

PPPoE is defined in [RFC 2516](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc2516) and includes a discovery stage for locating PPPoE servers/access concentrators:

> **5. Discovery Stage**
>
> There are four steps to the Discovery stage.  When it completes,
> both    peers know the PPPoE SESSION_ID and the peer's Ethernet
> address,    which together define the PPPoE session uniquely.  The
> steps consist    of the Host broadcasting an Initiation packet, one or
> more Access    Concentrators sending Offer packets, the Host sending a
> unicast    Session Request packet and the selected Access Concentrator
> sending a    Confirmation packet.  When the Host receives the
> Confirmation packet,    it may proceed to the PPP Session Stage.  When
> the Access    Concentrator sends the Confirmation packet, it may
> proceed to the PPP    Session Stage.
>
> All Discovery Ethernet frames have the ETHER_TYPE field set to the
> value 0x8863.

Comment: "one or more Access Concentrators sending Offer packets "--- why more Access Concentrators are present? There is point to point relationship, how more than one Access Concentrators are present? 2 hosts are present between one link?

Comment: Multiple access concentrators are possible - e.g. in a shared local loop (xDSL) with multiple ISPs offering dial-up services. A point-to-point relationship is established with each AC - usually only a single one but multiple simultaneous relationships are possible as well.

Comment: But Layer3 with only PPP (not using ppoe)there exists more than one relationships?

Comment: Pppoe with Ehthnet you said multiple devices are possible through switch. But only PPP more than one relationships are possible? Or with PPP only two devices connection are possible by one link?

Comment: No, each PPP(oE) session is always point-to-point - between two hosts/devices. I wanted to point out that there can be sessions with multiple partners potentially.

Comment: You said more than one connection per link, but every single link uses full bandwidth of the channel, so how one host uses full bandwidth of the channel if more than one connection per link exists?

Comment: A Ethernet point-to-multipoint link can carry any number of PPPoE sessions (well, with the *session ID* field being 16 bit that makes 65,535 simultaneous sessions in theory).

Comment: But host to switch port is baseband, which gives permission to use full bandwidth, but if more than one connection per link, so how everyone using full bandwidth? The bandwidth should not be divided?

Comment: PPPoE doesn't change the inner workings of Ethernet which forwards frames by MAC address. Any link is multiplexed that way, each MAC-to-MAC path is multiplexed by the EtherType field, each IPv4-carrying frame is multplexed by its addressing, and so on.

Comment: You mean when one hosts  sending multiple frames for multiple hosts (multiple Mac addresses) but that  host sending multiple data with Multiplexing and treated as single data and uses full bandwidth of the link?